# What is the correct way to encode SAML request to the Azure AD endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

I am using the following code to encode the SAMLRequest value to the endpoint, i.e. the `XYZ` when calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/saml2?SAMLRequest=XYZ.

Is this the correct way to encode it?

```
    private static string DeflateEncode(string val)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true), new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            writer.Write(val);
            writer.Close();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert string to a base64 encoded string, then you can use the following way:

```
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(val));
Console.WriteLine(encoded);
return encoded;
```

Comment: If you’re a Microsoft partner, I recommend you visiting aka.ms/devchat for personalized support on Azure. It’s free and 24x5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks correct for the Http Redirect binding.

But don't do this yourself unless you really know what you are doing. Sending the AuthnRequest is the simple part. Correctly validating the received response, including guarding for Xml signature wrapping attacks is hard. Use an existing library, there are both commercial and open source libraries available.